# Devices are not working affecting my performance on Ubuntu especially my graphic card , Guys what to do?

Tags: drivers, graphics, amd-graphics, video-editor, gpu-driver

I am having this problem from the first time I installed Ubuntu, I tried to search for any solutions, but I couldn't find anyone mentioning how to solve the missing graphic card and other drivers.

I know that Ubuntu identify my drivers automatically and installs them, but for me, I couldn't see that "Maybe because I changed my built-in motherboard long ago"I don't know

This is affecting my overall performance and especially Davinci Resolve 16

If you can tell me how to solve this I will be so thankful.

This is my grep radeon results, red-colored all radeon:

```
lsmod  | grep radeon
radeon               1478656  2
ttm                   106496  2 amdgpu,radeon
drm_kms_helper        184320  3 amdgpu,radeon,i915
drm                   491520  15 gpu_sched,drm_kms_helper,amdgpu,radeon,i915,ttm
i2c_algo_bit           16384  3 amdgpu,radeon,i915
```

This is when I hit lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display':

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520] (rev 07)
    DeviceName:  Onboard IGD
    Subsystem: Dell Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
--
01:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M / R5 M330 / M430 / Radeon 520 Mobile] (rev 81)
    Subsystem: Dell Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M / R5 M330 / M430 / Radeon 520 Mobile]
    Kernel driver in use: radeon
    Kernel modules: radeon, amdgpu
```

My sincere

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: Done Bro! @Pilot6

Comment: The drivers are in place. You can use `DRI_PRIME=1` to run a game on AMD GPU.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try and tell you, but for my, Davinci Resolve it says something different, Check this picture:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TyfScWbRddy0KdW_8z_VdHEZjiqzWuK7/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I have no idea what Davinci Resolve is.

Comment: Davinci Resolve is a video editor needs a good graphic card to work on.


This is what appears when I try to hit lspci | grep -i graphic it doesn't show me the AMD card:

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520] (rev 07)

Comment: That is OK. It shouldn't show you the AMD, because there is no word "graphic" there as you can see. Run the program with `DRI_PRIME=1` prefix.

Comment: Don't feel insulted 

Can ou tell me how to make it work with DRI_PRIME=1? hahaha

Comment: Run the program from a teminal with this prefix. Like `DRI_PRIME=1 davinci` or whatever the binary file is called.

Comment: Ok, that's' great!
I will try it now
Thanks a lot bro!

Comment: For your radeoncard, are 2 modules loaded.  This seems not right for me. But I'm not good in this stuff.

Answer (score -1):

Your graphics card isn't particularly powerful. It's got less power than a GT545 which is from 2014. DaVinci Resolve will not work as expected regardless of which OS you run it on. Try and find the Adrenalin software for your system/card and see if you're able to update the drivers. Even then, you're not likely to get much better performance, but give it a try :)